# Convergence of exponential of Gaussian random walk

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems, moment-generating-functions

---

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ be iid. standard normal random variables. (Recall their moment generating function: $\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\lambda \xi_i}\right)=\mathrm{e}^{\lambda^2 / 2}$.) Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k, \quad \text { and } \quad X_n=\mathrm{e}^{a S_n-b n} .
$$

Show that
$$
X_n \rightarrow 0 \text { a.s. } \Leftrightarrow b>0
$$
but for any $r \geq 1$
$$
X_n \rightarrow 0 \text { in } \mathcal{L}^r \Leftrightarrow r<\frac{2 b}{a^2}
$$

---

here's my solution but I'm stuck on how I can justify removing the $n$ from the final inequality. Might be having a bit of brain fart but it's late.

Now let $r \geq 1$, then using Markov's inequality:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_n-0\right| \geq \varepsilon\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_n\right|^r \geq \varepsilon^r\right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left|X_n\right|^r}{\varepsilon^r}=\frac{\left\|X_n-X\right\|_r^r}{\varepsilon^r} \rightarrow 0$$

Using the moment generating function provided,
$$\frac{\mathbb{E}\left|X_n\right|^r}{\varepsilon^r}=\frac{e^{r(\frac{a^2r}{2}-bn)}}{\varepsilon^r} \to 0.$$

By the definition of convergence, there exists an $N$ s.t $\forall n \geq N,$ $$\frac{e^{r\left(\frac{a^2 r}{2}-b n\right)}}{\varepsilon^r} \leq \frac{e^{r\left(\frac{a^2 r}{2}-b N\right)}}{\varepsilon^r}$$
so we choose $N$ s.t.
$$\frac{e^{r\left(\frac{a^2 r}{2}-b N\right)}}{\varepsilon^r} =1 = e^0$$
then
$$\frac{a^2 r}{2}-b n < 0$$

Answer (score 2):

The "brain fart" happens when computing $E(X_n^r)$; notice that:
\begin{align}
E(X_n^r) &= e^{-bnr} E(e^{arS_n}) \\
&= e^{-bnr} \prod_1^n E(e^{ar \xi_1}) \\
&= e^{-bnr} \prod_1^n e^{\frac{a^2r^2}{2}} \\
&= e^{-bnr} e^{\frac{a^2r^2}{2} \color{red} n} \\
&= e^{\color{red} nr\left( \frac{a^2r^2}{2} - b \right)}
\end{align}
The rest of your proof carries on the same and you'll arrive at the right conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

$E|X_n|^{r}=Ee^{arS_n-rbn}=(Ee^{ar\xi_1})^{n}e^{-rbn}=e^{a^{2}r^{2}n/2}e^{-rbn} \to 0$ if and only if $r<\frac {2b}{a^{2}}$.